# Android - Button inside TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am building an Android application in which I would like to add a button inside the `TabLayout`. I understand that it is technically feasible but please confirm if it is the recommended approach in `Android`.

For the reference, below is the sample screenshot. I am looking for similar implementation but instead of displaying only image, I would like to display a checkbox along with a label.

[image]

Please help me understand the recommended approach and also please share if any reference in the official documentation about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no answers so far, I would like to share my research's key points.

It is not recommended to use icons or some other buttons within the TabLayout.

The TabLayout should be totally allocated in the full width otherwise the user experience will get negatively impacted when we add more number of tab items.